# test not recognized a a test, testNG netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, testng

I don't understand why, despite having an assert statement and a test tag, Netbeans still says "[No test executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSDtI.png)" and doesn't show this test [in the test results tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNqWf.png) after I run it.

```
@Test
public void testPrintClassOneStudentNoName() {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    String expectedOutput  = "Hello" + System.getProperty("line.separator");

    System.out.println("Hello");

    assertEquals(expectedOutput, outContent.toString());
}
```

For the record something like this:

```
@Test 
public void test() {

    Classroom instance = new Classroom();
    int expResult = 0;
    int result = instance.countStudents();
    assertEquals(result, expResult);
}
```

Shows up as intended.

Comment: The question is how are you running it? What is the difference in both the cases in terms of the framework used?

Comment: what's the use of the test? it doesn't actually test any of your own code.

Comment: Yeah that's just for example, in my test I create a classroom with a few students and then call printClass() which should print the names of the students in the class.

Comment: There's no difference in how I run both tests, I just have them both in a test class and then run the class.